# Como apago um elemento no python

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho uma banco de dados.

criei uma variável e atribui valores de uma coluna a ela
`x1 = dataobitos.SEXO`

há três valores distintos: "F", "M", "Indefinido".

preciso eliminar o "Indefinido", mas não consigo.

já tentei:

```
x2 = x1.drop("indefinido")
x2 = x1.remove("SEXO", "indefinido")
x2 = x1.remove("indefinido")
```

mas nada dá certo...
putz...

estou começando agora com essa ciência.

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor seu problema. Qual estrutura de dados está utilizando? Um array, lista, dataframe? Você está lendo esses dados de um banco de dados? Qual tipo de banco? Você quer remover somente depois da leitura ou quer apaga-los do banco de dados?

Comment: hehehe. desculpa. é um dataframe, excel. nao queria remover do bd, apenas criar uma variável sem um valor específico. na coluna "sexo" tenho apenas 3 valores possíveis, o 'm', f' e o 'indefinido'. queria colocar apenas o 'm' e o 'f' numa variável para fazer operações.

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é filtrar as linhas indesejadas do dataframe usando [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) e então selecionar somenta a coluna desejada:

```
df_filtrado = df.loc[df['SEXO'] != 'Indefinido']
coluna_sexo = df_filtrado['SEXO']
```